# Ignore jars while creating final jar for production

Tags: maven, maven-2

I am using some jars like junit which are required only for testing purposes. I am using maven dependency plugin to copy all the jars to the final zip file created using maven. Is there a way to avoid junit jars from getting copied?

Comment: JUnit should be scope "test" which will automatically not be packaged.

Comment: That sounds you're doing things wrong. How do you create the zip file via maven-assembly-plugin ? Can you show the pom?

Answer (score 0):

In configuration  put includeScope = runtime

```
 <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.9</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <!-- exclude junit, we need runtime dependency only -->
                                <includeScope>runtime</includeScope>
                                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/dependency-jar/</outputDirectory>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
```